# nodejs stream response in binary how to convert?

Tags: node.js, websocket

i have client websocket connecting to a third-party websocket,
every response that websocket sends is in the format below:

```
{
  type: 'binary',
  binaryData: <Buffer 1f 8b 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ab 56 4a ce 4f 49 55 b2 32 34 30 30 31 30 d0 51 ca 4c 51 b2 02 12 86 4a 3a 4a b9 c5 e9 40 36 90 51 92 99 9b 5a 5c 92 98 ... 26 more bytes>
}
```

in the api docs they've mentioned all responses are compressed into gzip format.
how it's possible to convert this data to readable format in nodejs?
thanks

Comment: I think that the gzip compression refers to the http request and should be handled by the http client

Comment: did you tried `response.binaryData.toString('utf-8')`? What's the output?

Comment: yes, i tried. the output is �VJ�OIU�240010�Q�LQ��J:J���@6�Q���Z\��[TffilhdjjnihlP.

Comment: I think that `type: binay` tell us that the buffer should be converted in base64. Can you try to convert to base64 and then to string? `const b64 = binaryData.toString('base64'); Buffer.from(b64, 'base64').toString('utf-8')`

Comment: @giacomoto output is the same

Answer (score 0):

the `binaryData` is indeed a gzip data (based on the signature `1f 8b`).
to decompress the gzip data you can use the following code

```
const zlib = require("zlib");
// yourCompressData in your case should be the binaryData in the question
zlib.gunzip(yourCompressedData, (err, decompressedData) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error("handler errors here :-)", err);
    return;
  }

  // The decompressedData is also a Buffer
  console.log("Decompressed Data:", decompressedData);

  // Convert the Buffer to a string if the uncompress data should be a string
  console.log("Decompressed String:", decompressedData.toString());
});
```

of course the convert data should be base and handle by the data you expect to get. for example if the data is audio file there is no reason to convert it to string